# PHP: Include non OOP file in class, use class functions in non OOP

Tags: php, oop, include

Following non OOP file (incOverview.php) :

```
<?php

echo show_value();
```

classView.php

```
<?php
class myView
{
    public function loadView()
    {
       include("incOverview.php");
    }

    public function show_value()
    {
        return 42;
    }
}

$objView = new myView();
$objView->loadView();
```

**This will not work, it's only a sample to explain my problem.**

I expect "12"

When i include this file in an PHP class, the global **function show_value** does not exists, as expected.
But it exists inside the class. Normally the included file must be changed to **$this->show_value();** but in this scenario it is not possible.

Is there a solution, to include this non OOP file into my class and the class handles all requested functions ?

Comment: Your question seems not clear. Try to give some context or why you need to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap functions in your non-oop file as a trait and include trait inside your classes. Or include your file outside the classes. And functions will be available in global namespace.

Comment: outside my class is not possible. The included file must use classes function. Global namespace is not possible.
I will check the traits